# Problems with data loading with Grakn 1.7.1

Tags: python, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I have a migration script that I use to load data into Grakn via the Python driver with Grakn Core 1.6.2. This works.

I have recently downloaded 1.7.1, but when I run the same migration script I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grakn/service/Session/TransactionService.py", line 161, in send
    response = next(self._response_iterator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 388, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 382, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = ""
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1589227241.242279000","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:48555","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1055,"grpc_message":"","grpc_status":3}"
>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "migrator.py", line 240, in <module>
    insertSchema(URI, KEYSPACE)
  File "/Users/johnnie/Documents/grain/insert.py", line 21, in insertSchema
    write_transaction.query(schema)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grakn/client.py", line 131, in query
    return self._tx_service.query(query, infer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grakn/service/Session/TransactionService.py", line 49, in query
    response = self._communicator.send(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grakn/service/Session/TransactionService.py", line 165, in send
    raise GraknError("Server/network error: {0}\n\n generated from request: {1}".format(e, request))
grakn.exception.GraknError.GraknError: Server/network error: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = ""
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1589227241.242279000","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:48555","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1055,"grpc_message":"","grpc_status":3}"
>

 generated from request: query_req {
[SCHEMA IS SHOWN HERE]
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest release of both the Python Grakn client and Grakn server? Grakn core 1.7 is not compatible with pre-1.7 clients.

Comment: I did `pip3 install grakn`, so I should have the latest Python Grakn client right?

Comment: Could you try `pip3 show grakn` and check the version? The command to upgrade version is `pip3 install grakn --upgrade`.

Comment: I did `pip3 install grakn --upgrade` and then ran `pip3 show grakn` and got this back:

Name: grakn
Version: 1.4.2
Summary: A Python client for Grakn
Home-page: https://github.com/graknlabs/grakn/tree/master/client-python

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when using session.transaction().read(), when it call TransactionService.py

Comment: This is not an answer, if you have the same issue, up vote the question & add comments under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Becaues Grakn Core 1.7.1 does not support KGMS
[Detail](https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/client-api/python)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write

```
 pip install --upgrade grakn-client
```

Sources: [python client api docs](https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/client-api/python)  and [pip install docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#usage)

(the `--upgrade` flag because it is already installed.)